# What is the nature of Man in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, men, nature

The nature of women is described within the Manusmriti as the following:

> Manu assigned to women sleep, sitting, ornament, lust, anger, dishonesty, malice and bad conduct.

So then what's *man's* nature? As I have yet to find anything regarding such.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, the following are from Manu Smriti.

> 3.55 Women must be honoured and adorned by their fathers, brothers, husbands, and brothers-in-law, who desire (their own) welfare
>
> 3.56. Where women are honoured, there the gods are pleased; but where they are not honoured, no sacred rite yields rewards.
>
> 8.28. In like manner care must be taken of barren women, of those who have no sons, of those whose family is extinct, of wives and widows
> faithful to their lords, and of women afflicted with diseases.
>
> 8.29. A righteous king must punish like thieves those relatives who appropriate the property of such females during their lifetime.
>
> 8.349. In their own defence, in a strife for the fees of officiating priests, and in order to protect women and Brahmanas; he who (under
> such circumstances) kills in the cause of right, commits no sin.
>
> 9.232. Forgers of royal edicts, those who corrupt his ministers, those who slay women, infants, or Brahmanas, and those who serve his
> enemies, the king shall put to death.

This is not to defend some of the statements of Manu Smriti but to say that the version we have may be highly modified/misunderstood. Indian society didn't run by Manu Smriti literally until the British/Westerners revived it. Who is to authenticate the correct version of the manuscripts those days ?

Comment: Is this really an answer to my question?

Comment: Well, if the question was only the second line about the duties of the man, then no. But you had added a prelude in the question with a certain perspective. So, this is fair I think.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the passage below is the appropriate answer to your question. It is an assessment of non-spiritual men and women in general.

> Man develops hankering and attachment for sense objects when he
> falsely begins to think that they will promote his good. Such
> attachment matures into craving, and it is from these intense desires
> that conflicts erupt among men. From conflicts arise uncontrollable
> anger. This is followed by delusion - complete inability to
> distinguish right and wrong, the proper and the improper. Delusion
> quickly swallows his moral sense completely. O good friend! **Man then
> becomes a zero as far as his humanity is concerned. He is as good as
> dead. He loses all the great values obtainable through human life. He
> merely exists absorbing food like a tree, and breathing like a pair of
> bellows. Due to his excitement with sensuous enjoyments, he knows not
> anything about his real nature, nor does he have any love and sympathy
> for others.**

**Srimad Bhagavata Purana XI.21.19–22**